# What is the difference between comparable and any?

Tags: go, generics, comparable, any

I have tried to use generics with Go, but I don't really understand when we use `any` or `comparable` as type parameter. Can someone help to understand these?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on what / how you want to use values of the parameter type. Constraints restrict what you can do with values of those types.

`any` is an alias for `interface{}` which allows any type. If a parameter can be of any type, that basically won't allow you to do anything with it because you have no guarantee what it will be.

The `comparable` constraints only allows types that are comparable, that is, the `==` and `!=` operators are allowed to use on values of them. This is good if you want to use the type as a key in a map (maps require key types to be comparable), or if you you want to find an element in a slice, and you want to use the `==` operator to compare the elements to something.

As an example, let's write a generic map-get function:

```
func get[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V, key K) V {
    return m[key]
}
```

The `K` key type must be `comparable`, else it cannot be used as the key type of some map (`m[K]V` in the example). `V` on the other hand shouldn't be constrained, the value type may be anything, and we're not doing anything with it (just returning a value of type `V`), so using `any` here is the best choice.

Another example, a slice-find function:

```
func find[V comparable](what V, s []V) int {
    for i, v := range s {
        if v == what {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

`find()` returns the index of the first occurrence of `what` in the slice `s`, and if it's not in the slice, returns `-1`. The type parameter `V` here must be `comparable`, else you couldn't write `v == what`, using `V any` would be a compile-time error. The constraint `comparable` ensures this `find()` function can only be instantiated with types (and called with values) where the `==` operator is defined and allowed.

Comment: So, `comparable` is good for `map`. I will try that to see what happen there. Btw, Thank @icza for the explanation.

Comment: @Teguh Yes, it's good for map keys, and it's good also for anything where you must use the `==` and/or `!=` operators.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `comparable` and `any` will change with Go 1.20 (Q1 2023) and (accepted) the proposal "[56548: spec: allow basic interface types to instantiate comparable type parameters](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56548)".

`any` will implement the comparable constraint (which it does not before Go 1.20).

[Go 1.20-rc1](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20#language) states:

> [Comparable types](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) (such as ordinary interfaces) may now satisfy comparable constraints, even if the type arguments are not strictly comparable (comparison may panic at runtime).
>
> This makes it possible to instantiate a type parameter constrained by comparable (e.g., a type parameter for a user-defined generic map key) with a non-strictly comparable type argument such as an interface type, or a composite type containing an interface type.

---

The principle is:

> After substitution, each type argument must ***satisfy*** the constraint (instantiated, if necessary) of the corresponding type parameter. Otherwise instantiation fails.

With "satisfy" being:

> A type `T` satisfies a constraint interface `C` if
>
> - `T` implements `C`; or
> - `C` can be written in the form `interface{ comparable; E }`, where `E` is a basic interface and `T` is comparable and implements `E`.

Example:

> Currently, `any` does not implement the comparable constraint.
>
> With the proposed change `any` will be permitted as type argument for comparable: `comparable` can be written as `interface{ comparable; E }` and thus the new rule applies, and `any` is spec-comparable and implements `E` (where `E` is the empty interface in this case).
>
> Currently, the type parameter `P` in the type parameter list
>
> ```
> [P interface{ comparable; fmt.Stringer }]
> ```
>
> cannot be instantiated with the type S
>
> ```golang
> type S struct {
>   data any
> }
>
> func (S) String() string
> ```
>
> because `S` is not strictly comparable.
> With the proposed change, `S` must only be spec-comparable (which it is) and implement `fmt.Stringer` (which it does).

("spec-comparable" are for types of [comparable operands](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators))
(as opposed to "strictly comparable", which is for the types in `comparable`, namely the set of (non-interface) types for which `==` and `!=` are defined and for which these operations are guaranteed to not panic)

The implementation as started:

- [CL 453979](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/453979): "`cmd/compile`: enable new comparable semantics by default"
- [CL 453978](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/453978): "`go/types`, `types2`: make the new comparable semantics the default"

Comment: *This will change* — what, will change? To be very honest, I don't think this answer should be posted under this question; icza's answer doesn't even mention the strictly comparable limitation. And I don't think it should be posted this early, since the Go specs haven't been amended yet. As of today, you are quoting non-normative references.